# What is the full set of legal parameters I can pass to a FBWebDialogs through presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

- I've looked through sample code on Facebook
  here:https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/feed-dialog-using-ios-sdk/
- and reviewed the class reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/3.2/class/FBWebDialogs/#presentDialogModallyWithSession%3Adialog%3Aparameters%3Ahandler%3A

Is there documentation on the full set of parameters I can pass FWWebDialogs?
Can I set the text within the "say something" text (I know you can set the caption and description).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The parameters listed at the bottom of https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/ are all allowed to be passed into the webdialog.  No you can't set the text within the say something field.  If you are using the native iOS 6 share controls you can set the text, however the user can change it.

Comment: Thanks odyth, is it safe to assume this is the full set of legal parameters?

Comment: To my knowledge yes, facebook's mobile sdk sort of provides wrappers for existing web apis