# How to post our predefined text and image on facebook using iOS FBDialogs

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api

Im using following code of FBDialogs to share the post on facebook. (our requirement i not to use SLComposer present)

**I want to share predefined text and image on the facebook post.**

```
- (void)postAStatusMessage
{

    // Check if the Facebook app is installed and we can present the share dialog

    FBLinkShareParams *params = [[FBLinkShareParams alloc] init];
    params.link = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share/"];

    // If the Facebook app is installed and we can present the share dialog
    if ([FBDialogs canPresentShareDialogWithParams:params]) {

        // Present share dialog
        [FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithLink:nil
                                      handler:^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results, NSError *error) {
                                          if(error) {
                                              // An error occurred, we need to handle the error
                                              // See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors
                                              NSLog(@"Error publishing story: %@", error.description);
                                          } else {
                                              // Success
                                              NSLog(@"result %@", results);
                                          }
                                      }];

        // If the Facebook app is NOT installed and we can't present the share dialog
    } else {
        // FALLBACK: publish just a link using the Feed dialog
        // Show the feed dialog
        [FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession:nil
                                               parameters:nil
                                                  handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
                                                      if (error) {
                                                          // An error occurred, we need to handle the error
                                                          // See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors
                                                          NSLog(@"Error publishing story: %@", error.description);
                                                      } else {
                                                          if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {
                                                              // User cancelled.
                                                              NSLog(@"User cancelled.");
                                                          } else {
                                                              // Handle the publish feed callback
                                                              NSDictionary *urlParams = [self parseURLParams:[resultURL query]];

                                                              if (![urlParams valueForKey:@"post_id"]) {
                                                                  // User cancelled.
                                                                  NSLog(@"User cancelled.");

                                                              } else {
                                                                  // User clicked the Share button
                                                                  NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Posted story, id: %@", [urlParams valueForKey:@"post_id"]];
                                                                  NSLog(@"result %@", result);
                                                              }
                                                          }
                                                      }
                                                  }];
    }
}
```

I present the facebook screen empty as follows,

[image]

But i want to share **`my predefine text with the one selected image`** how to achieve this?

Comment: I think you need to add your text in Parameters.

Comment: I'm afraid you can't, see here http://stackoverflow.com/a/16292198/99214